# test with jset fails if the component includes react-quill in nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm trying to test my next app with jest and react-testing-library, the test works fine until i add react-quill it give me those errers:
" Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `ForwardRef(LoadableComponent)`."
"Error: Uncaught [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

I'm importing react-quill with dynamic import and use it inside form uses react-form-hook like this:

```js
import FormItemInner from "../../ui/reusable/customForm/FormItemInner"
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import ReportAttachment from "./ReportAttachment";
import { ValidationMessage } from "../../ui/reusable/Reusable";

const QuillNoSSRWrapper: any = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
})


const ProofOfConcept: FC<{ getFiles: any, register: any, errors: any, control: any, translate: any, authTranslate: any }> = ({ getFiles, register, errors, control, translate, authTranslate }) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoaded(true)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div style={{ borderTop: '1px solid #BCBCBC59', paddingTop: '1rem' }}>
            <FormItemInner title={translate("impactTitle")} required description={translate('reportImpactDescription')}>
                <Form.Control
                    className="mb-4 gray_input"
                    id="inputReportImpact"
                    data-testid="inputReportImpact"
                    type="name"
                    {...register("impact", {
                        required: true,
                    })}
                />
                {errors?.impact?.type === "required" && (
                    <ValidationMessage
                        message={authTranslate("RequiredField")}
                    />

                )}
            </FormItemInner>
            <FormItemInner title={translate("summaryTitle")} required description={translate('reportSummaryDescription')}>
                <Controller
                    name="summary"
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field: { onChange, value }, }) => (
                        <QuillNoSSRWrapper className="wrapperClassName mb-4" theme="snow" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
                    )}
                />
            </FormItemInner>
            <FormItemInner title={translate("recommendationTitle")} required description={translate('reportRecommendationDescription')}>
                <Controller
                    name="recommendation"
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                        <QuillNoSSRWrapper className="wrapperClassName mb-4" theme="snow" value={value} onChange={onChange} />

                    )}
                />
            </FormItemInner>

            <FormItemInner title={translate("attachmentTitle")} description={translate('reportAttachmentDescription')}>
                <ReportAttachment getFiles={getFiles} translate={translate} />
            </FormItemInner>

        </div >
    )

}

export default ProofOfConcept
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```